# NullPointerException in HardwareRenderer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-hardware

I wish I had more information about this error but I just don't. I have a tool called `BugSense`(Now it is `Splunk MINT`) that sends crashes to a remote server and this is all I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.checkCurrent(HardwareRenderer.java:960)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$Gl20Renderer.destroyLayers(HardwareRenderer.java:1148)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.destroyHardwareResources(ViewRootImpl.java:576)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:973)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2448)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The interesting thing is that all of the error instances came from:

- BLU DASH 4.0
- They are all rooted
- They all had Mobile Net turned off
- They all had at least 12 running apps

So... what do you think?

- has anyone had a NPE in the HardwareRenderer class?
- Could it be a 'root' thing (i.e. an issue with the device being rooted)?
- Could it be a 'hardware' thing (i.e. an issue with the BLUE DASH 4.0)

Comment: Not just BLU Dash 4.0. I'm seeing the same on kyocera_rise_c5155. But other than that I don;t have anything else to add.

Comment: I found this same exception on SEMC MK16i. I don't know, what cause this too. :/

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30743

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=30743).

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the code is using an null object.

```
MyClass class;
class.doStuff(); // Will throw NullPointerException as class is null

MyClass newClass = new MyClass();
newClass.doStuff(); // Will work as newClass is pointing to an object.
```

As I do not have the offending code, I cannot help further. I would suggest you include the code at (HardwareRenderer.java:960), and the call route from the stack, as this is what is causing the exception.

Comment: `HardwareRenderer` is part of the Android operating system and OP was experiencing a bug in it.

Comment: Either you have passed in a null object to this class or an injector of this class, or I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I would recommend you try to recreate the problem using example code, and add that to the question so others can use it to find a solution.

Comment: @RobertFry It's been 3 years. I doubt OP even remembers this.

Comment: Still the question may help others with a similar issue. I have solved many problems in the past by looking at similar problems on this site.

Comment: This answer is of no use. Of course, a nullpointerexception is by definition calling a method on a non-initialized object. The point here is why this exception is triggered from the android HardwareRenderer class that we do NOT directly manipulate. I got a crash similar on crashlytics.